# GridView only removing the first item when an item is clicked. Java->Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-gridview

I have a GridView populated with TextViews. I would like it so that when the user clicks a TextView that TextView is removed from the GridView and the String displayed in that TextView is removed from an ArrayList. This worked originally in Java but when converted to Kotlin it stopped working and now only removes the first item no matter which is clicked.

Here is the Kotlin code:

```
grid_view!!.onItemClickListener = AdapterView.OnItemClickListener { _, _, _, _ ->
    val selectedItem = (tag_name as TextView).text.toString()
    itemList.indices.forEach {
        Log.d("Update", "Removing: " + selectedItem)
        itemList.removeAll { it == selectedItem }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, what's wrong about you?

Comment: I realized that I was, in fact, having two separate, unrelated problems. So I thought the second problem warranted its own question because the original problem was fixed, thanks to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have already answered in your previous question. if you don't know how to do, I'm still glad to help you to solve the problem. First, I'm not an android developer, but I think you need to obtain the `position` from the [OnItemClickListener](http://www.android-doc.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html#onItemClick(android.widget.AdapterView<?>, android.view.View, int, long)) and there is no need a `for` loop do such a thing, for example:

```
grid_view!!.onItemClickListener = AdapterView.OnItemClickListener { _, _, pos, _ ->
    itemList.remove(pos)
    //by convention in android you should operate view on an adapter rather than UI
    //                     v
    your_grid_view_adapter.run{
       remove(pos)
       notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I did not quite understand your answer in the comments of the other question. But I understand your answer here and it works perfectly now. Thank you!

Comment: @Roc47HS I'm sorry,I'm confused you by my bad english, I come from China, :)